# Predict where the bullet hits

Tags: c++, sfml

I am making a tower defense game with C++ and SFML. I have made the map, make the enemy move, and a little bit of the turret class. The turret should rotate towards the enemy, and shoot at it when I hit the spacebar. I think I made the rotating good. When I shoot I want it to calculate where the bullet hits the enemy, how do I do it?

This is my current code:

```
enemy->setOrigin(enemy->getGlobalBounds().width / 2, enemy->getGlobalBounds().height / 2);

float degrees = atan2(this->getPosition().y - enemy->getPosition().y, this->getPosition().x - enemy->getPosition().x) * 180 / PI;
degrees -= 90;

this->setRotation(degrees);

degrees -= 90;

if (sf::Keyboard::isKeyPressed(sf::Keyboard::Key::Space) && !this->spaceKey){
    //Bullet: map, posX, posY, degrees, distance
    this->entityManager->Add("Bullet", new Bullet(this->map, this->getPosition().x, this->getPosition().y, degrees, 500));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You, at first, have to define for us what is a hit in your game. If you want to hit something like rectangles, the easiest, but the worst way to check the hit is to 'simulate' the movement of a bullet frame by frame checking whether it hits something or not or goes out of bounds (you should do that methot only if you are very unexpierenced in programming). Other, much advanced way of checking the hit is doing a raycast. Since bullet goes straight, it forms a line, and raycast should help you to find the collider. I found a proper tutorial [here](http://permadi.com/1996/05/ray-casting-tutorial-table-of-contents/) about raycasting, but if it does not satisfy you, you could just easily find other one. If both ways of finding the collision place of a bullet do not satisfy you, you could just implement some kind of line-rectangle collision or something like that which would support your needs.